# Story Identification and review

Tags: discussion, story-identification

In this [story identification question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/174051/82805) there is this [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/174072/82805) which in addition to answering the question gives a review of the themes in the book and seems to contain quite a few personal opinions. I am not super comfortable with knowing what kinds of answers should be flagged based on different types of questions, but I was wondering, should this kind of answer be flagged in any way?

Comment: Other than it contains additional (or irrelevant) information, is there any reason why you would _want_ to flag it?

Comment: @Möoz Instead of just supplying the answer of what the series is, he starts to paint it in a negative light in discussing how it follows/breaks its own internal themes. It isn't necessarily a bad answer, it just seems like it isn't the kind of answer that the OP was looking for. It would work great on a question about the themes of the series, but doesn't seem as appropriate for an ID question is all. I could be wrong, I am still fairly new to the meta stuff on this site.

Comment: You're right that `story-identification` questions are _different_, however, in this case the answer is still technically an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## There's nothing *technically* wrong with that answer

You don't need to flag it as there's nothing actually *wrong* with it; it's:

- A valid answer
- Not spam
- Not rude/abusive
- Doesn't need moderator attention

In fact, it was [reviewed](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/116197) by a trusted user who found nothing wrong with it ([in its original state](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/174072/1)).

## Vote accordingly

A close or delete vote is not a **super down-vote**. Just because you disagree or don't like an answer, doesn't mean it should be deleted (or flagged), *that's what the down-vote is for*.

I agree that the answer starts to waffle and is only *barely* technically an answer because it says

> Definitely Codex Alera

in it. That's not substantial enough to make a 'good' answer and to *me*, it's worthy of down-votes. At this point however, three users have found the post 'helpful' enough to up-vote it.

## Format and improve

This site is designed around community participation; if you feel that the post can benefit from some edits, then go ahead and improve it.

In fact, I'd separate the 'answer' and 'review' parts using a horizontal rule (`<hr />`).

Comment: Thanks, as I mentioned above, I am still new to the meta side of the site and wanted to make sure I understood what kinds of things are appropriate before I did anything.

Comment: You can also add a horizontal line by just adding a `---` on a new line.

Comment: "Trusted user" :')

Comment: @edl or so the 'system' thinks, _we_ know better don't we? ;-)